# Kusto Query with PowerBI Parameter

Tags: powerbi, kql, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to create a direct query within PowerBI using a PowerBI Parameter to basically act as a filter for the data that is returned from source.
The source in question has billions of rows so loading is not an option.

I have created the Parameter and have connected to my Kusto instance but I can not seem to get the Kusto Query to work even without the parameter involved.

If I remove the Parameter declaration and change the KustoQuery to = "" it still doesn't like it.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Note -
The query works in Azure Data explorer and I see data in PowerBI when I just connect to source so I know my connection details are correct.

Thanks.

[image]

```
let

KustoParameterDeclareQuery = 
Text.Combine({"declare query_parameters(IPParam:string=", IPAddressParameter,");"}),

KustoQuery = "{<Source> 
              |where ipaddress == IPParam
              |take 10
              |sort by week desc}"
              ,

FinalQuery = Text.Combine({KustoParameterDeclareQuery,KustoQuery}),

    Source = AzureDataExplorer.Contents("<KustoServer>", "<KustoSource>", FinalQuery, [MaxRows=null, MaxSize=null, NoTruncate=null, AdditionalSetStatements=null])
in
    Source
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed- it was a syntax thing as I was missing speech marks around the parameter

```
let

KustoParameterDeclareQuery = 
Text.Combine({"declare query_parameters(IPParam:string=""", IPParam,""");"}),

KustoQuery = Text.Combine({"<Database> 
              |where ipaddress == """,IPParam,"""
              |take 10
              |sort by week desc"})
              ,

FinalQuery = Text.Combine({KustoParameterDeclareQuery,KustoQuery}),

Source = AzureDataExplorer.Contents("<Source>"
                                  , "<Database>"
                                  , FinalQuery
                                  , [MaxRows=null, MaxSize=null, NoTruncate=null, AdditionalSetStatements=null]
                                   )
in
    Source
```